# Oracle SQL Developer - JOIN on 2 queries with a one-to-many relationship

Tags: java, python, sql, oracle-sqldeveloper, jython

I have two queries that I'm trying to join together.

In `first_query` TABLE2.PROCESS_ID, every PROCESS_ID is unique in that table. In `second_query` though there are several PROCESS_ID's with the same number in TABLE3, so I think I have to do a one-to-many join. The `join_query` I have is giving me an error `ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended` which I'm assuming has something to do with the one-to-many relationship with the JOIN.

I'm not really sure how to resolve this. Any help would be much appreciated!

```
first_query = """
SELECT TABLE1.RULE_ID, TABLE2.STATUS, TABLE2.ERROR_MESSAGE, TABLE2.PROCESS_ID
FROM TABLE2 LEFT JOIN
     TABLE1
      ON TABLE1.RULE_ID = TABLE2.RULE_ID 
WHERE TABLE1.RULE_NAME IN ('TEST1', 'TEST2')   
"""

second_query = """
SELECT RECORDS_PROCESSED, PROCESS_ID, STATUS
FROM TABLE3
"""

join_query = """
SELECT RULE_ID, STATUS, ERROR_MESSAGE, PROCESS_ID
FROM (first_query) as query_1
INNER JOIN (second_query) as query_2
ON query_1.PROCESS_ID = query_2.PROCESS_ID 
GROUP BY PROCESS_ID desc
"""
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not select 4 columns and group by only one of them unles you include selected columns as part of aggregation fucntion(like max(), sum(),...). One of the options is this:

```
SELECT query_1.RULE_ID         --1
       , query_2.STATUS        --2
       , query_1.ERROR_MESSAGE --3
       , query_1.PROCESS_ID    --4
FROM (SELECT TABLE1.RULE_ID
             , TABLE2.STATUS
             , TABLE2.ERROR_MESSAGE
             , TABLE2.PROCESS_ID
      FROM TABLE2 
      LEFT JOIN TABLE1
      ON TABLE1.RULE_ID = TABLE2.RULE_ID 
      WHERE TABLE1.RULE_NAME IN ('TEST1', 'TEST2')) query_1
INNER JOIN (SELECT RECORDS_PROCESSED
                   , PROCESS_ID
                   , STATUS
            FROM TABLE3) query_2
ON query_1.PROCESS_ID = query_2.PROCESS_ID 
GROUP BY query_1.RULE_ID
         , query_2.STATUS
         , query_1.ERROR_MESSAGE
         , query_1.PROCESS_ID
```

Also please do consider using aliases like this(in your first query):

```
SELECT T1.RULE_ID
       , T2.STATUS
       , T2.ERROR_MESSAGE
       , T2.PROCESS_ID
FROM TABLE2 T2 
LEFT JOIN TABLE1 T1 ON T1.RULE_ID = T2.RULE_ID 
WHERE T1.RULE_NAME IN ('TEST1', 'TEST2')
```

Also, apply the same logic with aliases on your final query or else you will have a different kind of error : "**ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined**"

[Here is a small demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=fca40827e494f130e1e6ea673f0c1871)

Answer (score 0):

`CTE` (i.e. the `WITH` factoring clause) might help.

```
WITH first_query
     AS (SELECT table1.rule_id,
                table2.status,
                table2.error_message,
                table2.process_id
           FROM table2 LEFT JOIN table1 ON table1.rule_id = table2.rule_id
          WHERE table1.rule_name IN ('TEST1', 'TEST2')),
     second_query
     AS (SELECT records_processed, process_id, status FROM table3)
SELECT a.rule_id,
       a.status,
       a.error_message,
       a.process_id
  FROM first_query a INNER JOIN second_query b ON a.process_id = b.process_id
```

`GROUP BY` you used is invalid; you can't group results by only one column. If results have to be unique, use `select distinct`. If you have to use `group by`, specify all columns returned by `select` (which leads you back to what `distinct` does), or see whether some column(s) have to be aggregates - in that case, `group by` makes sense.

Also, you should **always** use table aliases. Without them, query is invalid as database engine doesn't know which table those columns (if they share the same name) belong to.